# Rails iterated query to SQL statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to convert ruby query to sql here is what I got so far:

```
sql2 = "SELECT teams.* FROM teams, (SELECT sum(goals) FROM players WHERE team_id = team_id);"
connection.execute(sql2)
```

and this is what I'm trying to write:

```
  Team Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams"
   (0.5ms)  SELECT SUM("players"."goals") FROM "players" WHERE "players"."team_id" = $1  [["team_id", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT SUM("players"."goals") FROM "players" WHERE "players"."team_id" = $1  [["team_id", 2]]
```

the above was created with : `Team.all.map {|t| puts "#{t.name} and #{t.players.sum(:goals)}"}`

a simple loop trough players, getting team name and summing team.players.goals

Ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Is there any special reason to not use Active Record?

Comment: `SELECT sum(goals) FROM players GROUP BY team_id` would do the trick. Or, if you want exactly what stupid AR does: `SELECT sum(goals) FROM players WHERE team_id IN (SELECT id FROM teams)`.

Comment: @BSeven The snippet on how AR does it, posted by OP, is a perfect answer on “why not to use AR.”

Comment: @mudasobwa - What do you mean by "The snipped"? What exactly is wrong with AR?

Comment: @BSeven typo: snippet. Anyway, AR does “N+1 select” aka “N+1 query.” Google for that.

Comment: @mudasobwa - I am familiar with the N+1 problem. It is well documented at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations. Wouldn't eager loading solve it in this case?

Comment: @BSeven Eager loading solves anything, save for resources :) I bet the task of OP came from homework or like, that’s why actually AR is out of scope.

Comment: SELECT sum(goals) FROM players GROUP BY team_id << this works fine I just need to get name as well with it. SELECT name, sum(goals) FROM players GROUP BY team_id

Comment: @Richardlonesteen Of course it works fine. Whether you needed a name, you should note that in your question. AR output you’ve posted misses a name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(goals) FROM players GROUP BY team_id
```

would do the trick. Or, if you want exactly what stupid AR does:

```
SELECT sum(goals) 
FROM players 
WHERE team_id IN (SELECT id FROM teams)
```

or, with a name of team to be returned as well:

```
SELECT teams.name, sum(players.goals) 
FROM players 
  JOIN teams ON (players.team_id = teams.id)
GROUP BY team_id
```

Comment: the name trows an error, and it would get players name. When I need the teams name, thats why I been selecting all teams. THANK you